# Error with Lambda Expression C++ in VS Code

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to sort an array `m` of class `measure` using a lambda expression as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct measure{
    int day;
    int cow;
    int change;
};


int main()
{

    int N;
    cin >> N;

    measure m[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        measure m_i;
        cin >> m_i.day >> m_i.cow >> m_i.change;
        m[i] = m_i;
    }

    sort(m, m + N, [](measure a, measure b) {return a.day < b.day;});
}
```

However, an error occurs when trying to build the task in VS Code (using C++17):

> error: expected expression
>
> ```
> sort(m, m + N, [](measure a, measure b) {return a.day < b.day;});
>                ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> Build finished with error(s).

I've tested this code on other compilers with no difficulties. Why is this error happening on VS Code?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Are you using C++98 compiler?

Comment: More then likely you need to enable C++11 or higher in your compiler.  Search google using "turn on C++11 <name_of_compiler>" and that should get you what you need.  Also, if you are using g++ like I suspect, add `-pedantic-errors` to your compile command so it will error out on the VLA that you declared.  Change that array to a `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't retell compiler messages in your own words. Cut and paste, full and unedited.

Comment: Once you get past the error, which I can't duplicate, you'll run into the fact that `sizeof(m)` is not the number of elements in the array. `m + N` works as the second parameter to `sort`. If you want this to be portable you should use something like `std::vector` because variable length arrays are not standard C++.

Comment: pasted compiler message. I am using a C++17 compiler

Comment: question has been edited to reflect recent developments

Comment: `sizeof(m)` produces the size in bytes, not a count of elements. You already know the count of elements - that would be `N`

Comment: fixed problems with N

Comment: `using C++17` it seems you are still not using C++17.

Comment: try to write it like: sort(m.begin(), m.end(), [](measure a, measure b)  -> bool {return a.day < b.day;});  Ignore this, I agree with rest of the people, the requester doesn't uses a C++17 compiler.

Comment: "I am using a C++17 compiler" [no you are not](https://godbolt.org/z/3jax6Gq8E)

Comment: Would you mind pasting the actual command executed in the vscode?

Comment: `cin >> N;  measure m[N];` is not allowed in C++! It is a non portable extension...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it does not look like you are compiling with c++17. I can reproduce this error if I roll back the `gcc` version to `4.x` and leave the standard up to the compiler. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IzWgPU1HM6wJv8sU) is how it would look on an older compiler. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ajkIj5OhO848ciAd) is how it would run properly on a newer compiler. Most likely that you are using something like `c++98` or `c++03`.

*Note* - I have taken the liberty of modifying your code to make it more C++. Also, please stop with `using namespace std`.

A simple fix is to just make sure that you are using the right version of the compiler basis the features you need. Lambdas in C++ were introduced in C++11, so clearly you are using a compiler that is at a much lower version.

- VS Code does not have a compiler built-in. It uses the system compiler you have installed. You can configure things to use the system compiler and pass the flag `--std=c++17` to the compiler command line.
- Both gcc and clang++ support this command line flag.

Comment: OP uses VSC, not VS.